# Why is data not displayed when viewDidLoad finished in swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

When my application finished being launched, there are supposed to be data displayed on UITableViewCell. However, there is nothing there, so after relaunch the app, by pressing home button and swiping up the view, and select my demo app, all data is shown up properly and there seems like nothing is wrong. What causes the initial problem? Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: can you show  some code?

Comment: Which part? It is kind of a lot so I cannot tell where the problem is lurking... I mean it is not only to a UITableView, but to all my UITableVIew. Though only first launch. Second launch is fine...

Comment: How do you get the data that you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the `tableView.dataSource` to `self`? Also, you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` for populating the datas. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh. I did not call tableView.reloadData() in any UITableVIew files. Thanks!!! I guess it is solved!

Comment: Wait, do I need tableView.dataSource in UITableView as well as tableView.loadData() if UItableViews are not delegated

Comment: Also, assign data source to self before calling reloadData()

Comment: Should I write them in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Yep... You should

Comment: But whenever data changes, I mean new data adds to the source or removes, don't forget to call reloadData()

Comment: Ah. It was a good learning. Thank!

Comment: Also I wonder if there is another place reloadData and dataSource can be written and what if I write reloadData first and dataSource second?

Comment: No you have to write dataSource first, otherwise how tableView will know from where to load data

Comment: You can reload data wherever you deem necessary, as long as dataSource is assigned correctly

Comment: Okay ,thnaks very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you use UITableView, dont forget to call self.tableView.reloadData() after downloading data.