# Swift 3 Load JSON in Tableview

Tags: json, tableview, swift3

I'm currently working on an app and I would like to display the data I got from a JSON webpage in a TableView... My code to save the JSON-data in an array already works as I can print them every time in the console but the data doesn't load in the tableview and I tried almost everything: changing the cell identifier, using custom cells, etc... Anyone ideas on how to solve this problem?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var names: [String] = []
    var rating: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url=URL(string:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.0460761,3.7286716&radius=300&type=bar&key=AIzaSyCpHkY1s-qZjTOyTvDjMgD6hr5VTtEOgpU")

        do {

            let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = allContacts["results"] {
                for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {

                    let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]

                    names.append(aObject["name"] as! String)
                    rating.append(aObject["id"] as! String)
                }
            }

            print(names)
            print(rating)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        catch {

        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count;
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) {
        print("You selected name : "+names[indexPath.row])
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if !(cell != nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text=self.names[indexPath.row]
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = self.rating[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }


}
```

[As you can see he gives me the 2 lists...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ4X2.png)

Comment: you did not set your `TableViewController` as the `dataSource` of the `tableView`. That is a key point you missed in your interface setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer from this link... [Why is data not displayed when viewDidLoad finished in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289456/why-is-data-not-displayed-when-viewdidload-finished-in-swift/40292971#40292971)

The reason is most probably you haven't set `dataSource` and `delegate` of `tableView` to self. Try adding this codes in your `viewDidLoad()`. Hopefully your problem will be solved

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: If i do this I get an error: "Value of type UITableView has no member datasource...

Comment: Did you inherit `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` to your `UIViewController`? If you inherit them, it will get the members

Comment: Ok it's working now :D Thnx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `TableViewController` does not confirm the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and you also you did not set   `tableView.dataSource = self` and `tableView.delegate = self`

Use the following code snippet

```
  class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.dataSource = self
         tableView.delegate = self
      }
}
```